# Current Induction Explanation

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, field-theory, induction

Using
$$F_\text{magnetic} = (BIL)_\text{wire} = (BQv)_\text{particle}$$
we can say $F\propto v$ as $B$ and $Q$ are presumably constant.

Is the magnetic force proportional the radius, or distance, apart like in electric and gravitational fields?

Logically it makes sense; however, I've seen no proof of this.

Using this proportionality do we then say as the distance between the magnet and charged particle changes, so does the velocity of the charged particle; and as $I = Anev \rightarrow I \propto v$, the current subsequently goes up.

Comment: Please try to make questions clear. *"Logically it makes sense; however I see no proof of this"* <-- in that sentence, we don't know what "it" or "this" mean.

Comment: There's no distance involved at all.  $B$ is the field at the location of the charge or current.

Comment: "*Is the magnetic force proportional to separation?*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $F=BIL$ represents the force on a wire carrying current $I$ of of length $L$ within a uniform magnetic field of magnitude $B$, where $B$, $F$, and $L$ are mutually perpendicular.

On the other hand, $F=BQv$ represents the force on a single particle of charge $Q$ travelling with a speed $v$ transversely through a uniform magnetic field of magnitude $B$.

Those forces are not functions of distance.  They are both forces acting on the wire or particle.  They describe different scenarios and putting the forces equal does not make sense.

You could consider the average transverse force acting on a particle travelling at a uniform speed $v$ through a distance $L$ in the same transverse $B$ field, calculate its equivalent current, $I$, as $Q/t$, where $t$ is the time taken to traverse the distance, and you would find $$F_{average}=BQv_{average} = B \times I t \times \frac{L}{t} = BIL$$
That's the only (immediately apparent to me, at least) meaningful equality that can be made between the forces.

If you want to consider the dependence of *other* particles or wires at a distance from the current carrying wire or moving charged particle, then you should look at the [Biot-Savart law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law) and [these notes](http://academic.mu.edu/phys/matthysd/web004/l0220.htm), respectively.

EDIT:
I've added the following from the comments since this seemed to be answer the question better for the OP (and because I believe the answer should stand by itself without the comments).

Regarding the dependence of "magnetic force with separation":

The magnetic field exerted by a moving charge (or current carrying wire) on another charge (or current carrying wire) decreases with distance. For a single particle, it falls off as an inverse square whereas for an infinite (!) current carrying wire, it's inversely proportional. However, for an infinite plane of current, the magnetic field (and therefore the force exerted on a charged particle) is constant.

Comment: Is the magnetic force proportional to separation?

Comment: The magnetic field exerted **by** a moving charge (or current carrying wire) **on** another charge (or current carrying wire) decreases with distance.  For a single particle, it falls off as an inverse square whereas for an infinite (!) current carrying wire, it's inversely proportional. However, for an infinite plane of current, the magnetic field (and therefore the force exerted on a charged particle) is constant.

Comment: If that doesn't answer your question, then please edit your question to be more precise.

Comment: "*decreases with distance*," thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> do we then say as the distance between the magnet and charged particle changes, so does the velocity of the charged particle

The relationships $F=(BIL)_{\mathrm{wire}}$ and $F=(BQv)_{\mathrm{particle}}$ tell us only the relationship between an instantaneous force at a point in space. They tell us *nothing* about the general nature of the magnetic field.

If the particle moves to a different region where $B$ is different, the instantaneous force will be different.

The behavior of the magnetic field which produces the force depends on the specific source of the field. It may be due to magnetized material or a current in a wire. The spatial dependence of the field depends on the geometry of the source. In general, as one moves farther away from the source, the field will become weaker. In some specialized cases, such as a solenoid, there may be a small region (we're talking about areas on the order of a few cm$^2$) with near-constant B.

Devices which require constant B fields usually have multiple sets of wire coils which must be adjusted regularly to minimize non-uniformities.

Regarding the velocity of the particle, the force is dependent on the instantaneous velocity but acts perpendicularly to the velocity. If the magnetic force acts by itself, the velocity will change direction only and the force will change direction, but not magnitude. The magnitude of the force will not change unless the particle is subjected to some other force, or the external B changes.